# What does "OP" stand for?

Tags: support, acronyms

From the context in which I read "OP" in comments and answers, I understand that it refers to the person who asked the question, but I can't find any reference to the meaning of those letters, nor can imagine it.

Comment: Original Poster (no need to delete this I think it's a great question)

Comment: [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=op) is often a good place for finding the meaning of such abbreviations.

Comment: Kept me thinking for a while too, when I first saw it.

Comment: I use [Acronym Finder](http://www.acronymfinder.com/OP.html) which tends to lists most of the definitions associated with an abbreviation.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It means 'Original Poster', and is pretty common in for example Usenet (where you have a thread starting potentially with an anonymous question).

For a complete list of Stack Exchange terms, see [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40353).

Comment: Thanks for the glossary link too!

Answer (score 12):

In addition to "original poster," it is also sometimes used to mean "original post," with the assumption that you can tell which is meant based on the context.